Outerplanar embedding algorithm
Does anyone know of an algorithm that can produce an outerplanar embedding of a graph? I am looking for something similar to check_planarity from NetworkX, which returns a planar embedding if the graph is planar, with each node knowing the clockwise order of its incident edges. The counterexample is not necessary.
Even just pointing me to relevant literature so I can hopefully implement this myself would be really helpful. Or any ideas on how I could go about this would also help me a lot too!
Some definitions from Wikipedia:
In graph theory, a planar graph is a graph that can be embedded in the plane, i.e., it can be drawn on the plane in such a way that its edges intersect only at their endpoints. In other words, it can be drawn in such a way that no edges cross each other. Such a drawing is called a plane graph, or a planar embedding of the graph.
An outerplanar graph is an undirected graph that can be drawn in the plane without crossings in such a way that all of the vertices belong to the unbounded face of the drawing. That is, no vertex is totally surrounded by edges.
This is part of a network routing experiment I am doing. I have tried searching for related literature in this context, but I believe I might need to be searching in graph theory or something more mathematical to find out more about this.

For anyone who might have the same issue, here is how I solved it:
#1) Augment the outerplanar graph to a biconnected outerplanar graph:


def make_biconnected(graph):
    # Find cut vertices
    cut_vertices = list(nx.articulation_points(graph))

    for v in cut_vertices:
        neighbors = list(graph.neighbors(v))

        # Partition neighbors into blocks based on biconnected components
        subgraph = nx.Graph(graph)
        subgraph.remove_node(v)
        blocks = []
        for component in nx.connected_components(subgraph):
            block_neighbors = [n for n in neighbors if n in component]
            if block_neighbors:
                blocks.append(block_neighbors)

        # Add edges between blocks to make the graph biconnected
        for j in range(len(blocks) - 1):
            u = blocks[j][-1]
            w = blocks[j + 1][0]
            if not graph.has_edge(u, w):
                graph.add_edge(u, w)

                # If the edge breaks outerplanarity, revert and try other combinations
                if not is_outerplanar(graph):
                    graph.remove_edge(u, w)
                    for u_alt in blocks[j]:
                        for w_alt in blocks[j + 1]:
                            if not graph.has_edge(u_alt, w_alt):
                                graph.add_edge(u_alt, w_alt)
                                if is_outerplanar(graph):
                                    break
                                graph.remove_edge(u_alt, w_alt)

    return graph



#2) Find the largest simple cycle (this should be the Hamiltonian cycle or the outer face) and use the node ordering to create a circular layout


def generate_pos(graph):
    cycles = list(nx.simple_cycles(graph))
    maxLength = max( len(l) for l in cycles )
    path = list(l for l in cycles if len(l) == maxLength)
    pos = nx.circular_layout(path[0])
    return pos



#3) With the positions in #2 and the edges from the original outerplanar graph, use some math to sort the neighbor list of each node in ccw order and add the edges into an embedding.


def convert_to_outerplanar_embedding(graph, pos):
    # Step 1: Create a PlanarEmbedding object
    planar_embedding = nx.PlanarEmbedding()

    # Step 2: Assign the cyclic order of edges around each node based on positions
    for node in graph.nodes:
        neighbors = list(graph.neighbors(node))
        
        # Sort neighbors counterclockwise based on angle relative to the node's position
        neighbors.sort(key=lambda n: math.atan2(pos[n][1] - pos[node][1], pos[n][0] - pos[node][0]))

        # Step 3. Add edges in sorted order to the embedding
        planar_embedding.add_half_edge(node, neighbors[0])
        for i in range(1, len(neighbors)):
            u = neighbors[i-1]
            v = neighbors[i] 
            planar_embedding.add_half_edge(node, v, ccw = u)
    return planar_embedding



The result can be plotted using nx.draw_planar and should look like an outerplanar graph. I haven't tested it extensively, but it works so far for my use case.
